# Unexpected behavior when updating items in a Dictionary

Tags: excel, vba

I am storing values of cells within a dictionary when a Workbook is opened.  The Dictionary key is the cell address starting in A3 and going to A60 since these will be unique values, the Dictionary Items are generated with a class module based on the values from the offsets of Rows in Column A.
I noticed when running my `UpdateLoanDictionary` procedure that a new Key of the dictionary is added instead of updating the existing Key in the Dictionary (in this case the Key that was added was T5), when it should have updated the value of cell T5 based on the key of A5 and I am not sure why since I am very new to Class Modules and Dictionaries within VBA.

**Class Module**

```
Option Explicit

'--- Class: LoanData
Public LoanAmount As String
Public TitleCompany As String
Public Notes As String
Public CloseDate As String
Public PurchasePrice As String
Public Product As String
Public LoanNumber As String
Public CustomerName As String
Public Processor As String
Public Sub Populate(ByRef loanDetails As Range)
    With loanDetails
        LoanAmount = Trim(.Offset(0, 16).Value)
        CloseDate = Trim(.Offset(0, 10).Value)
        Notes = Trim(.Offset(0, 19).Value)
        LoanNumber = Trim(.Offset(0, 0).Address(False, False))
        Product = Trim(.Offset(0, 17).Value)
        PurchasePrice = Trim(.Offset(0, 15).Value)
        TitleCompany = Trim(.Offset(0, 4).Value)
        CustomerName = Trim(.Offset(0, 1).Value)
        Processor = Trim(.Offset(0, 2).Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

**Workbook Open Event**

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Not isReadOnly(PIPELINEFILE) Then
        Dim uname As String
        uname = LCase(Environ("username"))
        Select Case uname
            Case Is = "zacke"
                CreateLoanDictionary
            Case Else
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
Public Function isReadOnly(ByVal fName As String) As Boolean
    If Len(fName) > 0 Then
        isReadOnly = GetAttr(fName) And vbReadOnly
    End If
End Function
```

**Standard Module called NewDict**

```
Option Explicit
Private AllLoans As Dictionary
Public Sub CreateLoanDictionary(Optional ByVal forceNewDictionary As Boolean = False)
    '--- if the dictionary already exists, we don't have to recreate it
    '    unless it's forced
    If forceNewDictionary Or (AllLoans Is Nothing) Then
        Set AllLoans = New Dictionary
        Dim loanNumbers As Range
        Set loanNumbers = Sheet1.Range("LoanNums")
        Dim lNum As Range
        For Each lNum In loanNumbers
            UpdateLoanDictionary lNum
        Next lNum
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub UpdateLoanDictionary(ByRef thisLoanNumber As Range)
    '--- just in case this Sub is called before the dictionary is created
    If AllLoans Is Nothing Then CreateLoanDictionary
    'If IsEmpty(thisLoanNumber.Value) Then Exit Sub

    Dim thisLoan As New LoanData
    thisLoan.Populate thisLoanNumber

    If Not AllLoans.Exists(thisLoan.LoanNumber) Then
        AllLoans.Add thisLoan.LoanNumber, thisLoan
    Else
        AllLoans(thisLoan.LoanNumber) = thisLoan
        Debug.Print thisLoan.LoanNumber
    End If

End Sub
Sub ShowLoans()
    If AllLoans Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "This is no loan dictionary!"
    Else
        If AllLoans.Count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "There is a loan dictionary, but it's empty!"
        Else
            Debug.Print "There are " & AllLoans.Count & " loans in the dictionary:"
            Dim loan As Variant
            For Each loan In AllLoans.Items
            Debug.Print "Loan Number: " & loan.LoanNumber & " Notes: " & loan.Notes
            Next loan
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**Worksheet Event**

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    CreateLoanDictionary
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False


    Dim lnNotes As Range
    Set lnNotes = Sheet1.Range("LoanNotes")

    Dim NotesChangedCells As Range
    Set NotesChangedCells = Intersect(Target, lnNotes)
    If Not NotesChangedCells Is Nothing Then
        Dim changedCell As Range
        For Each changedCell In NotesChangedCells
            UpdateLoanDictionary lnNum
        Next changedCell
    End If


    Dim rgCells As Range
    Set rgCells = Me.Range("pNames")

    Dim rgSel As Range
    Set rgSel = Intersect(Target, rgCells)

    Dim cell As Range

    If Not rgSel Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In rgSel
            Select Case LCase(cell.Value)
                Case Is = "zack", "terri", "hunter"
                    Dim oLoan As New LoanData
                    With oLoan
                        .LoanAmount = Format(Trim(cell.Offset(0, 14).Value), "Currency")
                        .CloseDate = Trim(cell.Offset(0, 8).Value)
                        .Notes = Trim(cell.Offset(0, 17).Value)
                        .LoanNumber = Trim(cell.Offset(0, -2).Value)
                        .Product = Trim(cell.Offset(0, 15).Value)
                        .PurchasePrice = Format(Trim(cell.Offset(0, 13).Value), "Currency")
                        .TitleCompany = Trim(cell.Offset(0, 2).Value)
                        .CustomerName = Trim(Split(cell.Offset(0, -1).Value, " - ")(0))
                        .Processor = Trim(cell.Offset(0, 0).Value)
                        If .LoanAmount = "" Or .Product = "" Or .CloseDate = "" Or .Notes = vbNullString Then
                            MsgBox "Sorry, but you need to provide a minimum of:" & vbCrLf & _
                                   "Loan Amount" & vbCrLf & _
                                   "Product" & vbCrLf & _
                                   "Closing Date:" & vbCrLf & _
                                   "Interest Rate:" & vbCrLf & _
                                   "In order to assign a loan processor.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
                        Else
                            CreateEmail oLoan.Processor, oLoan.CustomerName, oLoan.TitleCompany, oLoan.CloseDate, _
                                        oLoan.PurchasePrice, oLoan.LoanAmount, oLoan.Product, oLoan.Notes
                        End If
                    End With
            End Select
        Next cell
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `Set AllLoans(thisLoan.LoanNumber) = thisLoan`

Comment: @TimWilliams  Seems to still update the key to T5 and not update the items for key A5.  Maybe im not printing the keys correctly in the `ShowLoans` Sub and am getting the wrong information in the immediate window?

Comment: Are you using the Watch window at all here?  You need to be very careful when using that to debug dictionary problems - it can auto-create entries from watches...

Comment: When and how are you calling `UpdateLoanDictionary` ?  Seems like you're passing in the wrong range at some point.

Comment: I am not using the watch window.  I call the `UpdateLoanDictionary` in the `CreateLoanDictionary` procedure.

Comment: That's the only way it ever gets called ?  Would help to show a sample of the output which illustrates the problem

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @TimWilliams I see what its doing now.  When i update the cell (T5) in that row, the `UpdateLoanDictionary` sub is passing that updated cell as the new key due to the `ByRef thisLoanNumber As Range` when it should be updating the Notes variable in the Class Module.  How do I fix that because there are other cells that will be updated as well.

Comment: "When I update the cell (T5) in that row" - how does that call the update procedure?  All you've shown is the call from CreateLoanDictionary.  That can't be all your code.

Comment: @TimWilliams I think i figured it out.  And you are correct I forgot to put the `Worksheet_Change` event code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finally.  When cell T5 value changed I wasnt passing the offset of cell T5 as the key for the dictionary, which caused cell T5 to be a new key instead of updating the items in the dictionary based on the key of A5.

Below is what I changed in the `Worksheet_Change` event and it now updates the Class Module and Dictionary accordingly.

```
Option Explict

Dim lnNotes As Range
Set lnNotes = Sheet1.Range("LoanNotes")

Dim NotesChangedCells As Range
Set NotesChangedCells = Intersect(Target, lnNotes)
If Not NotesChangedCells Is Nothing Then
    Dim changedCell As Range
    Dim lnNum As Range
    Set lnNum = NotesChangedCells.Offset(0, -19)
    For Each changedCell In NotesChangedCells
        UpdateLoanDictionary lnNum
    Next changedCell
End If
```